# New bib(la)tex-entrytype for music-scores

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, music

Short question: How can I create a new entry type (`@music`) with fields for the composer, title, opus, editor, series, location and year?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@music{citekey,
    composer={Johann Sebastian Bach},
    title={Motetten},
    number={BWV 225--230},
%   opus={}, % no opus in this case
    editor={Konrad Ameln},
    series={Neue Bach-Ausgabe Serie III, Band 1},
    loaction={Kassel},
    publisher={Bärenreiter},
    year={1965},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\cite{citekey} should look like

Johann Sebastian Bach: Motetten. BWV 225-230, hrsg von Konrad Ameln
= Neue Bach-Ausgabe Serie III, band 1. Kassel: Bärenreiter, 1965

or in general

(composer): (title)[, (opus)][, (number)][hrsg. von (editor)][= (series)].
[(location)][: (publisher)][, (year)][.]

where (xxx)=field and [yyy]=optional

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{music}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{usera}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{userb}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{=\addspace}
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\bibliography{9}
\begin{document}
\cite{citekey} should look like

Johann Sebastian Bach: Motetten. BWV 225-230, hrsg von Konrad Ameln
= Neue Bach-Ausgabe Serie III, band 1. Kassel: Bärenreiter, 1965

or in general

(composer): (title)[, (opus)][, (number)][hrsg. von (editor)][= (series)].
[(location)][: (publisher)][, (year)][.]

where (xxx)=field and [yyy]=optional

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the corresponding `.bib` file:

```
@music{citekey,
    usera={Johann Sebastian Bach},
    userb={myopus},
    title={Motetten},
    number={BWV 225--230},
    editor={Konrad Ameln},
    series={Neue Bach-Ausgabe Serie III, Band 1},
    location={Kassel},
    publisher={Bärenreiter},
    year={1965},
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! That works fine :-D. But is it right that I can’t declare new fieldnames like `opus` or at least make `opus` as a synonym for `usera` like `location` and `adress`?

Comment: @Tobi No, this is not possible at the moment because of bibtex, since biblatex has to define its entrytypes in the `.bst` file. I've read somewhere that this might be possible when biblatex will only work with biber, which is targeted for version 2.0 of biblatex.

Comment: Thanks for a great solution. On thing does not work for me however: in authoryear style, no year is showing up in the end. Any idea how i could fix this?

Comment: @johlie It's because the `authoryear` style redefines the `date` macro: `\renewbibmacro*{date}{}`. If you add `\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}` to my code before `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` you should get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much Thorsten! Do you as well know how to change, so that when I cite these @music posts, it uses the publisher instead of the editor, for example: Bärenreiter (1985), but without changing the citing of books, and all other articles?

Comment: @johlie This is very possible. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to figure it out at the moment. Maybe you'd like to ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 7):

My answer builds heavily on Thorsten's answer. I added the following modifications:

- Instead of using a custom field for the composer, I made use of the `author` field and the bibmacros built upon on it. Otherwise (as in Thorsten's example), bibliography entries will be listed under the composer in the bibliography, but in-text citations will show the editor's name instead (which I suppose is not what one wants).
- The format of the custom field used for the opus should default to "op.~" plus the field's content (so there's no need to type "op.~" every time). I have customized the format so that it will use the contents of the field `userc` as prefix if this field is defined (e.g. as "BWV").
- I have added support for back-referencing. These references may be turned off by removing the respective package option.

The content of the `series` field should probably be split up into separate fields, but I have left it alone for now.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,backref=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{music}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
%   \printfield{usera}% DELETED
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}% NEW
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{userb}%
%   \newunit\newblock% DELETED
  \newunit% NEW
  \printfield{number}%
%   \newunit% DELETED
  \newunit\newblock% NEW
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{=\addspace}
  \printfield{series}%
%   \setunit{\adddot\addspace}% DELETED
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
%   \newunit\newblock% DELETED
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock% NEW
  \usebibmacro{pageref}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}% DELETED
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}% NEW
\DeclareFieldFormat{userb}{% NEW
  \iffieldundef{userc}{%
    op.~#1%
  }{%
    \printfield{userc}~#1%
  }%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% NEW

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@music{citekey,
  author = {Johann Sebastian Bach},
  title = {Motetten},
  userb = {225--230},
  userc = {BWV},
  editor = {Konrad Ameln},
  series = {Neue Bach-Ausgabe Serie III, Band 1},
  volume = {1},
  location = {Kassel},
  publisher = {Bärenreiter},
  year = {1965},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Ein wenig Text \autocite{citekey}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also a great solution. How could I change the code, to use the publisher in the citation, for example \citet{abc} would generate Henle (1965)? Thank you!