# How to get a custom citation type in BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I would like to cite a movie in a paper I'm preparing. The style is APA, so (according to [this document](http://www.american.edu/library/documents/upload/Film-Video-Citation-Guide.pdf)) the citation in the text should be "(Mulcahy, 1986)" and the reference itself should appear as

Mulcahy, R. (Director). (1986) *Highlander*. Cannon Films.

I'm using BibDesk to manage my references, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of motion picture entry type. For now I can achieve the desired effect by entering it as a book, with `Cannon Films` as the publisher and `{Mulcahy, R. (Director).}` as the author. The citation in the text comes out as "(Mulcahy, R. (Director)., 1986)", but I can achieve the right appearance by entering "`(Mulcahy \citeyear{MUL86})`".

However, this is obviously a hack, and I'd like to know if there's a "right way" to do what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: I'm aware that there are a few existing questions concerning how to cite movies in BibTeX, but none of them cover this particular issue.

Comment: If you can use biblatex: Take a look at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/new-biblatex-entrytype-for-music-scores](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/new-biblatex-entrytype-for-music-scores), how to create a new entrytype for music-scores. You should be able to transfer this into a movie-entrytype.

Comment: Could you use `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`? It seems to be easier to customize styles: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles (instead of extending an existing .bst by a `movie` entry type... which would be "the right way" IMHO)

Comment: @musicman I guess I'll think about switching to biblatex for the next paper, as it sounds better. For now though, I have a deadline looming, so I was wondering if there's a right way to do it in bibtex.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder see my comment above

Answer (score 4):

The main BibTeX style files recognize a "catch-all" entry type called `@misc`. It would seem OK to use it for entries of type "movie".

If you use the bibliography style `apalike`, you'll get this output:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mulcahy86,
 author  = "Mulcahy, R. {\relax (Director)}", % don't abbreviate "Director"...
 year    = 1986,
 title   = "Highlander",
 howpublished = "Cannon Films",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % select your preferred bibliography style here
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet{mulcahy86}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you use the `apa` document class (which provides its own bibliography style), you'll get this:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{apa} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{mulcahy86,
 author  = "Mulcahy, Russell {\relax (Director)}",
 year    = 1986,
 title   = "Highlander",
 howpublished = "Cannon Films",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet{mulcahy86}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing to Biblatex might be a smaller step than you think. At least it can be a smaller step than fixing this some other way.

Here is an example, using `biblatex-apa`. I had to add lines stating that the director should be used as author in citations of movies. Otherwise this is out of the box. I added the `natbib` option to get the same commands like `\citep` which you might be used to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{apamovie.bib}

\DeclareLabelname[movie]{
  \field{director}
}

\begin{document}
I've read a book \citep{book}.
I've seen a movie \citep{highlander}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@Book{book,
  author =   {A. U. Thor},
  title =    {My first book},
  publisher =    {Methuen},
  year =     1999}

@movie{highlander,
  title =        {Highlander},                  
  director =     {Mulcahy, Russell},
  year =         {1986},
  publisher =    {Cannon Films},                  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you make available the modifications you had to make to get this result?

Comment: I did in the example, but I notice Biber/Biblatex has changed so this doesn't work anymore. Sorry, I don't have time to examine why now.

Answer (score 1):

How about using roles?

This answer is based upon [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579758/14628][1].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  author = {A. U. Thor},
  title = {My first book},
  publisher = {Methuen},
  year = {1999}
}
@book{highlander,
  title = {Highlander},
  author = {Mulcahy, Russell},             
  author+an:role = {1=director},
  year = {1986},
  publisher = {Twentieth Century Fox},                  
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
I've read a book \cite{book}.
I've seen a movie \citep{highlander}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```