# Customising biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

The solution shown in [How to get a custom citation type in BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169489/how-to-get-a-custom-citation-type-in-bibtex/169506#169506) is copied here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{apamovie.bib}

\DeclareLabelname[movie]{
  \field{director}
}

\begin{document}
I've read a book \citep{book}.
I've seen a movie \citep{highlander}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@Book{book,
  author =   {A. U. Thor},
  title =    {My first book},
  publisher =    {Methuen},
  year =     1999}

@movie{highlander,
  title =        {Highlander},                  
  director =     {Mulcahy, Russell},
  year =         {1986},
  publisher =    {Cannon Films},                  
}
```

[image]

How to get this output like below

[image]

Our university requirement is like as belows,

[image]
[image]
[image]

How to make it possible

Comment: Note that your requirements are highly inconsistent: Sometimes the initials go before, sometimes after the last name. Many entries have the year moved to the front, some don't. In the first entry the volume of the journal is not bold, in the second it is. Sometimes there is a comma before the title, sometimes a full stop, sometimes nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print authors in bold, just redefine the formatting

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

To make the bibliography numbered but staying with author-year style have a look here: [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style)