# Add publisher field to Music biblatex entry

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, books, musicology

I have this sample file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliografia.bib}
@Book{Zarlino1558,
Title = {L'istitutioni harmoniche},
Author = {Zarlino, Gioseffo},
Publisher = {Francesco de' Franceschi},
Year = {1558},
Address = {Venezia},
}

@Music {Venturi1592,
Author ={Stefano Venturi del Nibbio},  
Title ={Il primo libro di madrigali a 5},  
Address ={Venezia},  
Publisher ={Angelo Gardano},  
Year ={1592}
}



\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\mkbibnamelast\textsc%

\let\mkbibnamefirst\textsc%

\let\mkbibnameprefix\textsc%

\let\mkbibnameaffix\textsc

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%

{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}{}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Sezione}
Questo è un test.\nocite{Zarlino1558} \nocite{Venturi1592}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I would like to add a publisher field for my music type entries, which should appear between address and year, like for other books type entries.

Comment: Can you just use @Book? Will the result be formatted any differently from a book entry?

Comment: `@Music` is supposed to be a `musical recording` entry type, not a musical publication entry type. Why don't you use @Book?

Comment: This might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/new-biblatex-entrytype-for-music-scores/17649#17649

Comment: I could use @Book, but I need it in a separate subbibliography. Is there any way to tag books so that they can appear in separate bibliographies? Like this: \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Opere teoriche},type=book]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Opere musicali},type=music]

Comment: You can use `keywords` if you can't separate by `type`. Please note that in standard `biblatex` the type `@music` is just an alias for `@misc`, while some other styles implement `@misc`. Also  note that `@music` and `@audio` are intended to be used for audio recordings and not necessarily for a book(let) of written scores.

Comment: Since `@music` is with standard styles simply an alias of `@misc` you can use `organization` instead of `publisher` if you wish to continue using `@music`.

Comment: The problem seems to have been gotten around in the comments, but the question as posed is a duplicate of [New bib(la)tex-entrytype for music-scores](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17627/35864), so I'm voting to close as such.