# Has anybody implemented Society of Automotive Engineer (SAE) style bibliographies with a biblatex/biber solution?

Tags: biblatex, biber, package-writing

There already exists an [SAE class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sae) on CTAN contributed by Axel Franke, which although it is 15 years old (last update 2000-11-14) is still workable with a few tweaks, I think. The problem I am facing is that there is no SAE bibliography style file that exists as far as I know (I was looking for an SAE.bst for traditional bibtex). I started down the road of creating a new bst file based on the ieeetr style (which itself is based on the plain style), but I found this was cumbersome and still difficult to get exactly what I needed to satisfy specific [SAE publication requirements](http://volunteers.sae.org/authors/FormattingCitations.pdf). I would like to modify the SAE class to bring it up to date, and provide a biblatex solution (similar to the package biblatex-phys).

SAE is unfortunately very MSWord-centric, and they only have template files in MSWord. Citations are currently handled by most people I know using Endnote/Word with a custom Endnote output style and reference type for SAE papers (mainly to include the text "SAE Technical Paper YYYY-01-NNNN" for the paper number as part of the citation).

I'm not sure that the biblatex-phys package would be the best place to start for this, or if anybody has done something similar for SAE papers in the past?

Comment: Before you do this work, are you sure that they'll accept LaTeX submissions?

Comment: And before you then start trying to get a `biblatex` stile going, better check if they can accept that. See [`biblatex`: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Too often publishers that accept LaTeX files rely on old systems that cannot handle `biblatex`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright - The official word on this from SAE is the following: Does SAE have a template for LaTex users? 
No, Microsoft Word is the preferred software.  If you do not have access to Microsoft Word and must use 
LaTex, please follow the SAE Microsoft Word template as a guide. Upload the native files when asked for the 
source file in MyTechZone. Be sure that your PDF is we
ll-proofed as this is what will be used to apply XML to 
your document. http://volunteers.sae.org/authors/techpaperfaq.pdf

Comment: It seems like it will work, although I admit I have not tried it and don't know anybody that has. I'm tempted to try it with a manuscript that I have written in word, and if they get the output completely wrong at least I have the fallback. I'm not exactly sure of their process for going from pdf to xml as they say, and how that would affect the final look of the document. In general though, it seems that with SAE journals, all formatting is done by the authors. I'll see if they will respond to an e-mail on this though to get details.

Comment: Anyway, on to your question. It seems fairly probable that there is until now no such style for `biblatex` available at the moment (googling didn't turn up anything). You should probably start with the style that comes closest to what you need and simply modify that. You can find lots of questions about particular changes on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [formatting guidelines](http://volunteers.sae.org/authors/FormattingCitations.pdf) are missing some `biblatex` data types and seem a bit inconsistent.

The following should get you started. We modify the `numeric` standard style of `biblatex`, but you could take any other standard `numeric-...` style as basis.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  %\setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{urlseen = {accessed}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,kullback,geer,markey}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: My reputation is not yet high enough to upvote your answer, but it is very useful and has me started in trying to understand the biblatex documentation. My next question in relation to this (and please let me know if I should start a new thread for this) is how to create a new *.bib reference type, i.e. article / book / etc. For example, in Endnote, I can create a custom "Reference Type" called "SAE Technical Paper", which has a field called "SAE Paper#". This number can be referred to in the bibliography style for "SAE Technical Paper", and includes the text "SAE Technical Paper 950513".

Comment: @R.K.G. If you want to implement a new type you better ask a new question for that, but have a look around first, there have been some questions about that already, see [New bib(la)tex-entrytype for music-scores](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17627/35864) and [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864). But maybe it is enough to add a new field to an already existing type (`@article` or `@report` maybe) [Add new field to biblatex entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65374/35864).

Comment: @R.K.G. But if you have a new specific question that is not already covered by other questions on this site feel free to ask. But please make the question more specific than this question here.

Comment: That sets me down a promising new path. I'll try something like that and start a new thread if I have too much trouble adding a new field to the standard classes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a style almost 20 years ago during my PhD studies. It's still available on Dante: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/sae/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The class already got a shout-out in the question (with a link to CTAN), but this is specifically about a bibliography style for the SAE. So I can't help but feel that this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've just published my updated version of Axel Franke's SAE template. For the bibliography I use the ieee transaction's style: `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` which is close enough so that the SAE editors accepted it as is.

My template is available on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sae-tech-papers-updated-template/mkzqytmhrszt