# How to make a URL link underline in Bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

I just want to make my URL link underline.

For example below:
[image]

I can provide my MWE if needed.
I am thinking is it just add some commend like:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

Comment: That is not really an underline, it is a hyperlink, see the hyperref package

Comment: @daleif I dont think is here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Hyperlinks

Comment: It is the same thing, note also it may be an artifact of the 9df viewer. The the hyperref manual for details

Comment: @daleif could you write an answer?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292064/how-do-i-underline-the-doi-in-the-bibliography-using-biblatex-biber-context-c

Answer (score 2):

Underlining in LaTeX is hard and I would in general try to avoid it as much as possible.

One way to get an 'underlined' URL is to fake the underlining with the boxes around links in `hyperref`. This is only a faked underline though since the boxes are not printed. See for example [How can I have colored and underlined links with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26071/35864).

Another method is explained in [How do I underline the DOI in the bibliography using biblatex/biber? (Context: continued work on SAE class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292064/35864) (and stolen from [I cannot get a (properly) underlined hyperlink in blue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23208/35864))

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
  \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlfrom = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\ULurl{#1}}
```